# Make objects fall when someone enters trigger (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Collapse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Rigidbody rb2;
    public Rigidbody rb3;
    void Start()
    {
        rb.useGravity = false;
        rb2.useGravity = false;
        rb3.useGravity = false;
    }
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
        {
            if (coll.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                rb.useGravity = true;
                rb2.useGravity = true;
                rb3.useGravity = true;
        }
        }

}
```

This is what I have so far but it just doesnt seem to work. I basically want 3 objects to fall out of the sky when a player crosses a certain trigger, i've set up the Trigger and linked the 3 rigidbodies. the start function works and disables the gravity on the 3 objects. However I cant get the second part to work, after the player crosses the trigger, the gravity doesnt get re-enabled.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            rb.useGravity = true;
            rb2.useGravity = true;
            rb3.useGravity = true;
    }
    }
```

Problem :
You cannot access tag dirctly from collider

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh NVM I fixed it, I think my trigger was not big enough